# jQuery - lazyload on newly replaced images

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, lazy-loading

I'm trying to use lazyload high-resolution images with low-res replacements, using this plugin: https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/. According to the author, high-resolution image is defined by 'data-src' attribute, and low-res by 'src' attribute.

I have JS code that looks like the following:

```
function set_attr() {

    //... some codes before

    $('.banner-and-background').attr('data-src', 'path/myImage.jpg');
    $('.banner-and-background').css('background-image', "url(" + 'path/myImage_min.jpg' + ")");

}
function imgLazy() {
    $('div.lazyload').lazyload({
        effect: 'fadeIn'
    })
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    set_attr();
    imglazy();
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="banner-and-background lazyload"></div>
```

My codes snippet doesn't apply the lazyloading effect that I want. What am I doing wrong here?